# error on existing AKS 1.27.3 with Azurerm 2.99.0

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I am getting below error, On currently deployed Kubernetes terraform from registery

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/2.99.0/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster
'

it was working last week with Kubernetes version 1.27.3, two days ago MS removed 1.27.3 and now available version is 1.27.9, But even when I am trying to upgrade it giving below, I tried to use data block with azurerm 3.34.0 version but same error

'

'

;

containerservice.ManagedClustersClient#Get: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="NoRegisteredProviderFound" Message="No registered resource provider found for location 'westus2' and API version '2022-01-02-preview' for type 'managedClusters'. The supported api-versions are '2017-08-31, 2018-03-31, 2019-02-01, 2019-04-01, 2019-06-01, 2019-08-01, 2019-10-01, 2019-11-01, 2020-01-01, 2020-02-01, 2020-03-01, 2020-04-01, 2020-06-01, 2020-07-01, 2020-09-01, 2020-11-01, 2020-12-01, 2021-02-01, 2021-03-01, 2021-05-01, 2021-07-01, 2021-08-01, 2021-09-01, 2021-10-01, 2022-01-01, 2022-02-01, 2022-03-01, 2022-04-01, 2022-06-01, 2022-07-01, 2022-07-02-preview, 2022-08-01, 2022-08-02-preview, 2022-08-03-preview, 2022-09-01, 2022-09-02-preview, 2022-10-02-preview, 2022-11-01, 2022-11-02-preview, 2023-01-01, 2023-01-02-preview, 2023-02-01, 2023-02-02-preview, 2023-03-01, 2023-03-02-preview, 2023-04-01, 2023-04-02-preview, 2023-05-01, 2023-05-02-preview, 2023-06-01, 2023-06-02-preview, 2023-07-01, 2023-07-02-preview, 2023-08-01, 2023-08-02-preview, 2023-09-01, 2023-09-02-preview, 2023-10-01, 2023-10-02-preview, 2023-11-01, 2023-11-02-preview, 2024-01-01, 2024-01-02-preview'. The supported locations are 'australiacentral, australiacentral2, australiaeast, australiasoutheast, brazilsouth, brazilsoutheast, canadacentral, canadaeast, centralindia, centralus, eastasia, eastus, eastus2, francecentral, francesouth, germanynorth, germanywestcentral, israelcentral, italynorth, japaneast, japanwest, jioindiacentral, jioindiawest, koreacentral, koreasouth, northcentralus, northeurope, norwayeast, norwaywest, polandcentral, qatarcentral, southafricanorth, southafricawest, southcentralus, southindia, southeastasia, swedencentral, switzerlandnorth, switzerlandwest, uaecentral, uaenorth, uksouth, ukwest, westcentralus, westeurope, westus, westus2, westus3'

How do I fix the error, AS MS ended version 1.27.3 and when I ma changing 1.27.3 to 1.27.9

It is giving same above error

Any advise where I don't need to re-create the resource??

Comment: Need a bit clarity Chandra, please edit your question and elaborate your issue and fix the error msg output you shared. Also show azurerm provider version . You need to use one of the supported API versions for the managedClusters resource type in the westus2 location. You can check the API version in your code and update it to one of the supported versions.

Comment: please share the deployment configuration that you tried causing the error for better understanding of the query you asked for @chandrashekar

Comment: Azurerm Version is mentioned in Subject as 2.99.0 with Kubernetes version 1.27.3

Comment: I understand you provided versions It is better if you share terraform configuration or script so that the community will have a better understanding of your requirements @chandrashekhar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried Resolving Azure Kubernetes Service Deployment Errors with Terraform in West US 2 Region and I was able to provision the requirement successfully

The cause of the error is that the `westus2` location does not support the Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) API version you are using. The Azure API version (`2022-01-02-preview`) that you have specified in your Terraform configuration or by the Terraform AzureRM provider is the issue, not the Kubernetes version (1.27.3 to 1.27.9).

To fix this issue, make sure you are using the most recent version of the Terraform AzureRM provider. You said you tried version 3.34.0, but check if there is a newer version that has updated API versions or fixes for this problem.

To prevent the error message, ensure that your Terraform configuration is compatible with one of the API versions that the `managedClusters` resource accepts in `westus2`. If you have specified the API version yourself, switch to a valid version from the error message and when using the `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster` resource, avoid setting the API version explicitly unless required and execute a `terraform refresh` to sync the state with the actual infrastructure.

***My terraform configruation:***

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "aks_rg" {
  name     = "tstvk-rg"
  location = "westus2"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = "vkAKSCluster"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "vkakscluster"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_DS2_v2"
    orchestrator_version = "1.27.9" # Set the Kubernetes version here
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

***Deployment Succeded:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: i upgraded to 3.72 version which fixed it, Thanks

Comment: can you check this question as well

Unable to create Azure Function keys, using terraform azapi